# Error when switching to running applications - android

Tags: background, switch-statement, between

i have write a app to switch between background apps in android.
I'm get error when switch to system app (EX: com.android.setting)

My code:

```
try{
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString(pack
    + "/" + cclass)); 
    this.startActivity(i);
}catch(Exception ex){
    **//ex is null**
}
```

Thanks for help!